# Clicking on the "Deploy Mean Development Stack" does nothing, Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, mean-stack

[image]When clicking on the "Deploy Mean Development Stack" from the developer console within my project on Google App Engine it does not display a URL. The loading circle displays for a few seconds and then nothing. There is no URL or anything indicating that an application has been deployed? I have enabled billing and cloud storage. Is there some other setting I need to change so that this will deploy?

Comment: Could you upload the screenshot where you're stuck. This feature is very new and I don't get it from your comment. Link here https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mean/

Comment: I've added a screenshot. If I click on the blue button "Deploy MEAN Development Stack", a loading circle appears with a loading message saying it can take 5mins. Then nothing. It goes back to this screen as if nothing happened. My understanding is that there should be a URL of my deployed stack that I can visit.

Comment: Do you see errors in the Browser console (F12)? If so, what are they?

Comment: There is a POST 404 error: https://console.developers.google.com/m/deploy?pid=578800586012&cmd=customd…region=us-central1&app=mean&xsrf=U3qPe5wjhC1ZHUeAftLqpH6oUoU:1411563820255 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's currently an issue with this feature and it's not working as expected.